# immutable value ’self.calender’ may not be assigned to in swift3

Tags: swift, calendar

this is code which was previously written in Swift2.3 now I upgraded in swift3 so get the error **immutable value ’self.calender’ may not be assigned to in swift3** how I can remove this ?

```
 class DateNSDateConverter
  {
    /// The singleton instance
    static var sharedConverter = DateNSDateConverter()

    let calendar: Calendar
    let utc: TimeZone

    init() {
        calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        utc = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
  calendar.timeZone = utc; // error come here in this line 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

with

> let

you make the object immutable. Change the following from:

```
let calendar
```

to

```
var calendar
```